# Swift extension for a specific iOS version

Tags: ios, swift

I need to create custom extension for my class that depends on iOS version.

So, for instance:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
extension Foo {
    func test() {
        print("do something for iOS 10.0 and later")
    }
}
```

What if I would execute test for version between 9.0 (included) and 10.0 (excluded)?

Comment: You can't mark an extension with available. Just curious, why not add an availability check in the function?

Comment: @ebby94 Because it's not cool 

Answer (score 2):

I should appreciate you for asking this question.

**@available** works similarly to **#available** in that you specify the iOS release you want to target, and then Xcode handles the rest. For example:

```
@available(iOS 9, *)
func iOS9Work() {
    // do stuff
}
```

If your deployment target is iOS 8, you can't call that iOS9Work() method without some availability checking first. You can stack up these checks if you need to, for example:

```
//You need to perform this check before calling
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
    iOS9Work()
}

@available(iOS 9, *)
func iOS9Work() {
  // do stuff
}
```

In your case you have to call like this:

```
 if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        Foo()
    }
```

For more info: [Availability Checking in Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking)